# Do I need Kerbros when I want to configure external list?

Tags: external-list

I am assigned a task to configure external list, and I am reading that if I want to delegate authentication to external sources, I need to set up Kerbros, do I need to configure Kerbros on the environment for the external list to work as delegated user? as mentioned in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2010/05/09/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This depends on your configuration and what you need to happen.  It is possible to use a Secure Store account to connect to the external data, and that will not require Kerberos.  It does mean however that everyone gets the same level of data access to that external data, unless you place special permissions on the content type.

Comment: But using Secure Store Account means using claims token service? I am confused between all of these concepts. When do I use Kerbros to authenticate to external sources?

Comment: The claims2windows service is a special service for specific scenarios with certain service applications.  You can use SSS with BDC without the C2WTS ( in fact you can't unless you have some custom BDC connection that leverages it)